# kafka client could connect to kafka server run in the docker container

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using docker to run a zookeeper and kafka instance with the following commands

```
docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper
docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper -e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost -e HOST_NAME=localhost  debezium/kafka
```

ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is exposed outside container to localhost.

```
the kafka is connected to zookeeper and kafka output is as followed

        Using ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=172.17.0.3:2181
    Using KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    2020-07-26 03:56:23,160 - INFO  [main:Log4jControllerRegistration$@31] - Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
    2020-07-26 03:56:26,313 - INFO  [main:X509Util@79] - Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
    2020-07-26 03:56:26,554 - INFO  [main:LoggingSignalHandler@72] - Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP
    2020-07-26 03:56:26,580 - INFO  [main:Logging@66] - starting
    2020-07-26 03:56:26,593 - INFO  [main:Logging@66] - Connecting to zookeeper on 172.17.0.3:2181
    2020-07-26 03:56:26,700 - INFO  [main:Logging@66] - [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to 172.17.0.3:2181.
```

the code to connect the kafka server is below

```
const { Kafka,logLevel,CompressionCodecs,CompressionTypes } = require('kafkajs');

const kafka1 = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['localhost:9092']
});
```

but the kafka client could connect to kafka server with error "`{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2020-07-26T02:53:30.472Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Closed connection","retryCount":0,"retryTime":313}"`

Answer (score 2):

This behavior has to do with the `--link` flag. If you want to produce/consume data outside the docker network it will be required to add a lot of arguments to those docker run commands.

However, there is an easy(er) way to do it. Check out this [docker-compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/latest/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) file! Replace the image names with the ones that you want ( e.g: `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1` with `debezium/zookeeper` ), delete the services that you don't need and you're good to go!